# ¿Carga de archivos con Android php y mysql, multiples parametros en HttpURLConnection?

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

Hola a todos estoy aprendiendo a usar Android Studio descargue un [proyecto](http://www.coderefer.com/android-upload-file-to-server/) desde el [git](https://github.com/vamsitallapudi/AndroidUploadFileToServer) el proyecto funciona a la perfección e incluido algunos aportes como guardar el archivo que se carga a la base de datos; intento ahora poner la descripción del documento a cargar.

Esta función recibe la ruta del archivo a cargar:

```
public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath) {

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()) {
        dialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    } else {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty(
                    "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);
```

En esta parte creo que se le asigna el nombre al parametro a enviar y de esta manera Php lo recoge:

```
<?php
$file_path = "uploads/";     
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
```

> En lo que necesito ayuda es en enviar un segundo parámetro, algo como: 
>   connection.setRequestProperty("segundo_parametro",suvalor);

```
            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);


            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                try {

                    //write the bytes read from inputstream
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Insufficient Memory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            try{
                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Memory Insufficient!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/" + fileName);
                    }
                });
            }

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

            if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {

                wakeLock.release();
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

}
```

El error es que mi segundo_parametro no es recibido por Php

Comment: El segundo parametro de que propiedad???    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty(
                    "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

Comment: como un string, pero el comentario jorge es lo que tengo en la parte superior